# jquery function to the element that is being appended?

Tags: jquery, function, append

I'm trying to append some html stuff, and I was wondering how come when I try to write some jquery function, that element that was just appended won't work?

For instance, if I had a list of text and when you click on something, that list will populate with some sort of .append('more text') to that list. Then if I have written some jquery function saying when hovering over that text, it won't work. It will only work on text that was already populated before the append.

I hope my example clarifies my question?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you binding with .mouseover()/.bind() or with .live()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery's [`live()` method](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead of the regular event handler.  For example:

```
$('#myelement > *').live('mouseenter', function(evt) {
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
}).live('mouseleave', function(evt) {
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
})
```

now, when you do this

```
$('#myelement').append( '<div>More Stuff</div>' );
```

the newly added div will get the mouseenter and mouseleave events as you wanted.

Comment: Both answers helped me out! I checked it one because it was fast

Answer (score 1):

You are probably binding your handlers using `.click()`, `.hover()`, etc. These only work for items already on the page at the time the handler is bound.

Try using `.live(event, handler)` instead. This binds to elements which match now, and any elements that match that are added later.

e.g.

```
$('li').live('click', function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```